# Do logical operations in 2 column simmultaneously in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, sklearn-pandas

I have one Dataframe name df -

```
   id   year    month      target1  
0  324  2019.0  1.0        100.0    
1  325  2019.0  3.0        100.0   
2  326  2019.0  10.0       100.0    
3  327  2019.0  11.0       100.0    
4  328  2019.0  12.0       100.0
```

Now I want to compare 2 columns of the Dataframe namely 'year' & 'month', to get new dataframe like this -

```
   id   year    month      amount  
0  324  2019.0  1.0        100.0    
1  325  2019.0  3.0        100.0   
2  326  2019.0  10.0       100.0
```

Here the operations was -

```
year <= 2019
&
month <= 10
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas.

Similar operations could be -

```
year < 2019     &      month <= 6
year < 2019     &      month <  6
year < 2019     &      month <= 12
```

Any logic or way to achieve this result using Python3 or Pandas. 
I tried a logic where I simply compare the year and month separately, like this -

```
df_new = df[df['year'] <= year ]
df_new = df_new[df_new['month_num'] <= month_num ]
```

But this logic fail in case I have more than 1 year. By this I get this dataframe as output -

```
year <= 2020  &  month <= 1
   id year    month      amount 
0  3  2019.0  1.0        100.0     
5  9  2020.0  1.0        100.0
```

But ideally what I need is this -

```
   year    month      target1 
0  2019.0  1.0        100.0     
1  2019.0  3.0        100.0     
2  2019.0  10.0       100.0     
3  2019.0  11.0       100.0     
4  2019.0  12.0       100.0     
5  2020.0  1.0        100.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to print everything before the specified month of the specified year. This could be done in several ways

1. Simply add

```
data.query('(year == 2020 and month <= 1) or (year <= 2020)')
```

2. You can try to create a new column, which would use pd.to_datetime()

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you are looking to apply two conditions as df['condition1' AND 'condition2']. If that is the case, this might work:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['year'] <= 2019].loc[df['month'] <= 10]
```

I tried it with this dataset (multiple years):

```
'''
   id   year    month      target1  
0  324  2019.0  1.0        100.0
1  325  2019.0  3.0        100.0
2  326  2019.0  10.0       100.0
3  327  2019.0  11.0       100.0
5  328  2020.0  4.0       100.0
6  329  2020.0  12.0       100.0
7  330  2020.0  2.0       100.0
'''
```

Output of df1:

```
    id    year  month  target1
0  324  2019.0    1.0    100.0
1  325  2019.0    3.0    100.0
2  326  2019.0   10.0    100.0
```

If I change the condition for the year to this:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['year'] <= 2020].loc[df['month'] <= 10]
```

Output:

```
    id    year  month  target1
0  324  2019.0    1.0    100.0
1  325  2019.0    3.0    100.0
2  326  2019.0   10.0    100.0
5  328  2020.0    4.0    100.0
7  330  2020.0    2.0    100.0
```

Comment: ingeneral, `loc` chaining should be avoid.

Comment: Try this - 
df1 = df.loc[df['year'] <= 2020].loc[df['month'] <= 2], you will get the difference from what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple conditions like this:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(int)

df = df[(df['year'] == 2019) & (df['month'] < 10)]

   id  year  month  target1
0  324  2019      1    100.0
1  325  2019      3    100.0
```

Comment: This logic is same what I tried, I am not getting desired result from this.

Comment: What is not working? Did you add the conditions in brackets?